# Cannot embed C++/CLR Assembly Version number

Tags: c#, clr, assemblyversions

I'm using a C++ CLR DLL in my C# WinForms app (.NET 3.5).
I have set the assembly info according to all instructions found but when looking at my C# app in VS2015 the DLL metadata keeps displaying "0.0.0.0".

Here are some screenshots of my CPP and result:

Resource file - app.rc.
It also includes "version.h" shown below.

[image: App.rc]

version.h:

[image]

When I see the DLL file properties I can see the following:

[image]

But at the end, when I look at my C# code generated from the managed CPP, I can see that it is "0.0.0.0":

[image]

Is there something I'm missing here?
Thanks.

Comment: You cannot see it from the unmanaged resource editor, the assembly version is embedded in the CLR manifest header.  It is not obvious how this went wrong, especially given that the assembly appears to have a strong name.  When you create a new project from the C++ > CLR > Class library project template then you always get an AssemblyInfo.cpp file in the project.  Which has the [AssemblyVersion] attribute.  Be sure that your project has one.  And that you edit the default value, "1.0.*" is not a great choice.

Comment: Thanks @Hans Passant - This was quite useful as I've found that the generated Assembly info (in my C#) comes from the AssemblyInfo.cpp file as you've said (which I didn't include in the project).
All other .rc files and version.h will set the file version properties only.

Nevertheless, I see that the metadata on C# is not reflected even if you change the values, only when changing the C++ project name.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found myself facing the same (or a similar) issue: I had a CLI C++ library included in a solution and its assembly version was 0.0.0.0.

The only way I've been able to change it was to add a new source file called ***AssemblyInfo.cpp*** to che CLI C++ library containing the following lines:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Reflection;
using namespace System::Runtime::CompilerServices;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
using namespace System::Security::Permissions;

[assembly:AssemblyTitleAttribute(L"CliLibrary")];
[assembly:AssemblyDescriptionAttribute(L"")];
[assembly:AssemblyConfigurationAttribute(L"")];
[assembly:AssemblyCompanyAttribute(L"")];
[assembly:AssemblyProductAttribute(L"CliLibrary")];
[assembly:AssemblyCopyrightAttribute(L"Copyright (c)  2019")];
[assembly:AssemblyTrademarkAttribute(L"")];
[assembly:AssemblyCultureAttribute(L"")];

[assembly:AssemblyVersionAttribute("1.0.0.0")]; // <-- This is the version string

[assembly:ComVisible(false)];

[assembly:CLSCompliantAttribute(true)];
```

After recompiling the DLL I finally read **1.0.0.0** as DLL assembly version. Hope it helps someone else!